# AX-12 controller_manager not working

Tags: ros, ax12

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Out of the blue, the controller_manager from the ax12_controller_core has stopped working.  I am simply launching the file from the tutorial, but it says "Pinging motor IDs 1 through 5" then it says "No motors found, aborting."  There is nothing wrong with the power or the data cable.  We can manually control the servo through program we had in windows. But nothing happens in ubuntu and ROS.  Not sure what happened.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10137/ax-12-controller_manager-not-working/) by [a11irap](https://answers.ros.org/users/596/a11irap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-06-17**:
Has you sorted this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you working with USB2Dynamixel dongle? (you can check the device settings:

```
$ls -al /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Can you still control them in Window$? I had twice the problem that the ID's were flipped and I had to reset them. Can you still read out the ID's in the Dynamixel program?

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-02**:
no activity in  > 1 month, closing